# Customer Login Session

Tags: frontend, login, cookie

How can I change the amount of time of the customer login session? As an example, If a customer is shopping for several parts from a wholesale supplier they make take longer to shop. How can I increase the FRONTEND cookie lifetime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022952/set-session-time-out-limit-for-magento-frontend

Answer (score 1):

go to `System > Configuration > Web` in the `General Section > Session Cookie Management` panel on the right.

When you expand the panel you'll see an option ***Cookie Lifetime***. Change the number to whatever you want and click on the ***Save Config***.

Comment: On the server you need also extend setting of gc.session_lifetime

Comment: To confirm: That is for the front end for customers, correct? Not admin login?

Comment: I believe it's global.

Answer (score 0):

Also extent session.gc_maxlifetime as it's 1440 sec by default